# Sending data from an analytics engine to a Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an analytics engine which periodically packages a bunch of stats in JSON format. I want to send these packages to a Rails server. Upon a package arriving, the Rails server should examine it, generate a model instance out of it (for historical purposes), and then display the contents to the user. I've thought of two approaches.

1) Have a little app residing on the same host as the Rails server to be listening for these packages (using ZeroMQ). Upon receiving a package, the app would invoke a Rails action through CURL, passing on the package as a parameter. My concern with this approach is that my Rails server checks that only signed-in users can access actions which affect models. By creating an action accessible to this listening app (and therefore other entities), am I exposing myself to a major security flaw?

2) The second approach is to simply have the listening app dump the package into a special database table. The Rails server will then periodically check this table for new packages. Upon detecting one or more, it will process them and remove them from the table.

This is the first time I'm doing something like this, so if you have techniques or experiences you can share for better solutions, I'd love to learn.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can restrict access to a certain call by limiting the host name that is allowed for the request in routes.rb

```
post "/analytics" => "analytics#create", :constraints => {:ip => /127.0.0.1/}
```

If you want the users to see updates, you can use polling to refresh the page every minute orso.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you are exposing a major security breach unless :

1. Your zeroMQ app provides the needed data to do authentification and authorization on the rails side
2. Your rails app is configured to listen only on the 127.0.0.1 interface and is thus not accessible from the outside
3. Like Benjamin suggests, you restrict specific routes to certain IP

2) This approach looks a lot like what delayed_job does. You might wanna take a look there : https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job and use a rake task to add a new job.

In short, your listening app will call a rake task that will add a custom delayed_job when receiving a packet. Then let delayed_job handle the load. You benefit from delayed_job goodness (different queues, scaling, ...). The hard part is getting the result.

One idea would be to associated a unique ID with each job, and have the delayed_job task output the result in a data store wich associated the job ID with the result. This data store can be a simple relational table

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Result |
+----+--------+
```

or a memecache/redis/whatever instance. You just need to poll that data store looking for the result associated with the job ID. And delete everything when you are done displaying that to the user.

3) Why don't you directly POST the data to the rails server ?

Comment: For option 3, I do intend to post but I need to ensure the action is restricted to only approved entities (or am I missing something?). I'm going to try Benjamin's suggestion and report back in.

Answer (score 0):

Following Benjamin's lead, I implemented a filter for this particular action.

```
def verify_ip
  @ips = ['127.0.0.1']
    if not @ips.include? request.remote_ip
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

The listening app on the localhost now invokes the action, passing the JSON package received from the analytics engine as a param. Thank you.